# jquery UI draggable: ui.children is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, draggable, jquery-ui-sortable

i have a draggable list, a sortable-droppable list and a couple of li's inside the first.

now i want to pull them over, in the stop-funtion i have a function that adds a class to the first child (it's a span representing the clip-number like

```
<li>
    <span>1.</span>
    <span>Title</span>
    <span>1min23sec</span>
</li>
```

). the reason for this is, i want to represent the original clip number in the playlist(sortable).

but i get a console error saying

```
TypeError: ui.children is not a function
ui.children("li")[0].addClass(".slot_clip_info");
```

i am not 100% sure, but i think this exact code HAS already worked in the past time, i might have changed somthing without knowing, but i am not aware of that.
draggable:

```
$(function() {
    $(".pl_clipEntry").draggable({
        appendTo: "body",
        revert: "invalid",
        connectToSortable: "#tracks",
        distance: 20,
        helper: function(){
            return $(this).clone().width($(this).width());   // hack for the drag-clone to keep the correct width
        },
        stop: function(ui) {
            ui.children("li")[0].addClass(".slot_clip_info");
        },
zIndex: 100

     });
});
```

sortable:

```
$(function() {
    var removeItem;
    $("#tracks").sortable({
        items: "li:not(.placeholder)",
        connectWith: "li",
        placeholder: "sort_placeholder",
        helper: "clone",
        distance: 20,
        sort: function () {
            $(this).removeClass("ui-state-default");
            updatePlaylist();

        },
        over: function (event,ui) {
            updatePlaylist();
            removeItem = false;
            console.log(event);
            console.log(ui);

            var originalClass = ui.helper.context.childNodes[0].className;
            console.log(originalClass);

            var small_clip = originalClass.match(/(\d+)/g)[1];
            ui.item.context.children[0].innerHTML = small_clip;
            ui.item.context.children[0].classList.add("slot_clip_info");
        },
        out: function () {
            updatePlaylist();
            removeItem = true;

        },
        beforeStop: function(event,ui) {
            if (removeItem) {
                ui.item.remove();
            }
        },
        stop: function(event,ui) {

            console.log("checking placeholder");
            var list = $(this);
            var count = list.children(':not(.placeholder)').length;
            list.children('.placeholder').css("display", count > 0 ? "none" : "block");

            savePlaylist();
        }

    });
```

as soon as i pull and element IN or reorder them, i get the said error.
also, on refresh, the list seems to multiply itself.. but i guess that's another issue...

[Full fiddle (pretty messy, functionality in top dropdown button "PL TOGGLE"](https://jsfiddle.net/PSone/7egjrrnn/)

UPDATE: another thing i noticed: the first drag works without problems, then shows the error on release, subsequent drags will (mostly.. sometimes they do...) not work

Comment: Can you add a demo to show the issue?

Comment: i just copied EVERYTHING over, but the dragging doesn't work at all on the fiddle... no idea why (oh, and it looks REALLY ugly, sorry :D )
the lists i was talking about are on the "toggle pl" button on top.
idea: pull them from right to left.

https://jsfiddle.net/PSone/7egjrrnn/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need to make ui a jquery object, and then wrap the first element in another jquery object to do what you want.

so change:

```
ui.children("li")[0].addClass(".slot_clip_info");
```

to

```
$($(ui).children("li")[0]).addClass(".slot_clip_info");
```

Answer (score 1):

In jQuery UI's draggable module, the `stop` function has 2 parameters : `event` and `ui`.

`ui` is a **javascript** object (and not a jQuery one, there's a difference.)

This object has 3 attributes :

- `helper` which is a **jQuery** object
- `position` which is a **javascript** object
- `offset` which is a **javascript** object

Depending on your HTML code (we don't have), you could replace

```
ui.children("li")[0].addClass(".slot_clip_info");
```

by

```
ui.helper.children("li")[0].addClass(".slot_clip_info");
```

Comment: it says "ui.helper is undefined", but i think i got the idea. Rooster's answer worked for me. thanks to both of you